# Does iOS SDK support SVG as custom font?

Tags: ios, svg, uifont

I have a custom font in SVG-file. I've added it to the application's bundle same as i did it with OTF font. Now I'm trying to use it in code below:

```
UIFont * customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:16.0f];
```

And I am getting error:

> Apr  7 14:58:46 Alexander ExampleProject[26403] : FT_Open_Face failed: error 2.

I'm thinking iOS SDK just not supporting SVG-font yet because the same way works with OTF-font, but does not with SVG. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS SDK does not support SVG as a font.

But you could just convert the font, for example with http://www.freefontconverter.com/

Comment: I need to download custom font from server before use it. But thank you anyway :).